# Why does a simple loop result in ASYNC_NETWORK_IO waits?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

The following T-SQL takes about 25 seconds on my machine with SSMS v17.9:

```
DECLARE @outer_loop INT = 0,
@big_string_for_u VARCHAR(8000);

SET NOCOUNT ON;

WHILE @outer_loop < 50000000
BEGIN
    SET @big_string_for_u = 'ZZZZZZZZZZ';
    SET @outer_loop = @outer_loop + 1;
END;
```

It accumulates 532 ms of `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` waits according to both `sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats` and `sys.dm_os_wait_stats`. The total wait time increases as the number of loop iterations increases. Using the `wait_completed` extended event I can see that the wait happens roughly every 43 ms with a few exceptions:

[image: wait table]

In addition, I can get the call stacks that occur right before the `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` wait:

```
sqldk.dll!SOS_DispatcherBase::GetTrack+0x7f6c
sqldk.dll!SOS_Scheduler::PromotePendingTask+0x204
sqldk.dll!SOS_Task::PostWait+0x5f
sqldk.dll!SOS_Scheduler::Suspend+0xb15
sqllang.dll!CSECCNGProvider::GetBCryptHandleFromAlgID+0xf6af
sqllang.dll!CSECCNGProvider::GetBCryptHandleFromAlgID+0xf44c
sqllang.dll!SNIPacketRelease+0xd63
sqllang.dll!SNIPacketRelease+0x2097
sqllang.dll!SNIPacketRelease+0x1f99
sqllang.dll!SNIPacketRelease+0x18fe
sqllang.dll!CAutoExecuteAsContext::Restore+0x52d
sqllang.dll!CSQLSource::Execute+0x151b
sqllang.dll!CSQLSource::Execute+0xe13
sqllang.dll!CSQLSource::Execute+0x474
sqllang.dll!SNIPacketRelease+0x165d
sqllang.dll!CValOdsRow::CValOdsRow+0xa92
sqllang.dll!CValOdsRow::CValOdsRow+0x883
sqldk.dll!ClockHand::Statistic::RecordClockHandStats+0x15d
sqldk.dll!ClockHand::Statistic::RecordClockHandStats+0x638
sqldk.dll!ClockHand::Statistic::RecordClockHandStats+0x2ad
sqldk.dll!SystemThread::MakeMiniSOSThread+0xdf8
sqldk.dll!SystemThread::MakeMiniSOSThread+0xf00
sqldk.dll!SystemThread::MakeMiniSOSThread+0x667
sqldk.dll!SystemThread::MakeMiniSOSThread+0xbb9
```

Finally, I noticed that SSMS uses a surprising amount of CPU during the loop (about half a core on average). I'm unable to figure out what SSMS is doing during that time.

Why does a simple loop cause `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO`waits when executed through SSMS? The only output that I appear to get from the client from this query execution is the "Commands completed successfully." message.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql) for `SET NOCOUNT` says:

> `SET NOCOUNT ON` prevents the sending of `DONE_IN_PROC` messages to the client for each statement in a stored procedure. For stored procedures that contain several statements that do not return much actual data, or for procedures that contain Transact-SQL loops, setting `SET NOCOUNT` to `ON` can provide a significant performance boost, because network traffic is greatly reduced.

You are not running the statements in a stored procedure, so SQL Server sends [`DONE` tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/3c06f110-98bd-4d5b-b836-b1ba66452cb7) (code `0xFD`) to indicate the completion status of each SQL statement. These messages are deferred, and sent asynchronously when the network packet is full. When the client does not consume network packets quickly enough, eventually the buffers fill up, and the operation becomes blocking for SQL Server, generating the `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` waits.

Note the `DONE` tokens are different from [`DONEINPROC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/43e891c5-f7a1-432f-8f9f-233c4cd96afb) (code `0xFF`) as the documentation notes:

> - A `DONE` token is returned for each SQL statement in the SQL batch except variable declarations.
> - For execution of SQL statements within stored procedures, `DONEPROC` and `DONEINPROC` tokens are used in place of `DONE` tokens.

You will see a dramatic reduction in `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` waits using:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #P AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE
    @outer_loop integer = 0,
    @big_string_for_u varchar(8000);


WHILE @outer_loop < 5000000
BEGIN
    SET @big_string_for_u = 'ZZZZZZZZZZ';
    SET @outer_loop = @outer_loop + 1;
END;
GO
EXECUTE dbo.#P;
```

You could also use [`sys.sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) to achieve the same result.

Example stack trace captured just as an `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` wait begins:

[image: sending a packet]

An example TDS packet as seen in the inline function `sqllang!srv_completioncode_ex<1>` had the following 13 bytes:

```
fd 01 00 c1 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Which decodes to:

- TokenType = 0xfd `DONE_TOKEN`
- Status = 0x0001 `DONE_MORE`
- CurCmd = 0x00c1 (193)
- DoneRowCount = 0x00000001 (1)

Ultimately, the number of `ASYNC_NETWORK_IO` waits depends on the client and driver, and what it does, if anything, with all the `DONE` messages. Testing with a loop 1/10th of the size given in the question (5,000,000 loop iterations) I found SSMS ran for about 4 seconds with 200-300 ms of waits. `sqlcmd` ran for 2-3 seconds with single digit ms waits; `osql` around the same run time with around 10 ms of waits.

The worst client by far for this test was Azure Data Studio. It ran for almost 6 hours:

[image: ADS]